# Selecting a store location when webscraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping a grocery website (https://www.paknsaveonline.co.nz) to do some meal planning before I shop. The price of products varies with the location of the store. I want to extract prices from my local store (Albany).

I am new to web-scraping, but I am assuming my code must

1. change the default store to my local store (Albany, using this url: https://www.paknsaveonline.co.nz/CommonApi/Store/ChangeStore?storeId=65defcf2-bc15-490e-a84f-1f13b769cd22)
2. maintain a single requests "session", to ensure I scrape all of my products from the same store site.

My scraping code successfully scrapes the price of broccoli, but the price does not align with the price from my local store. At the time of posting my scraped price for broccoli is $1.99, but when I manually check the price at the Albany store, the price is $0.99.
I assume my code to switch to the correct store isn't working as intended.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and suggest a solution?

Environment details:

- requests==2.23.0
- beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
- Python 3.7.10

Code below, with an associated link to Google Colab file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

dollars_pattern = '>([0-9][0-9]?)'
cents_pattern = '>([0-9][0-9])'
url = 'https://www.paknsaveonline.co.nz/CommonApi/Store/ChangeStore?storeId=65defcf2-bc15-490e-a84f-1f13b769cd22'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}   }

with requests.session() as s:
  #I assume this url changes the store (200 response)
  s.get(url)
  #use the same session to return broccoli price
  r = s.get('https://www.paknsaveonline.co.nz/product/5039956_ea_000pns?name=broccoli')
  soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
  cents =  str(soup.find_all('span', {'class': "fs-price-lockup__cents"}))
  dollars =  str(soup.find_all('span', {'class': "fs-price-lockup__dollars"}))
  centsprice =re.findall(cents_pattern, cents)
  dollarsprice = re.findall(dollars_pattern, dollars)
  print(dollarsprice, centsprice)
```

[Google Colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15MIjlfdWgv9Kb86p-ueRCrDwFeOeUV2Z?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the actual requests of that you need to first get some cookies from base URL and then you can change the store for that session you cant directly modify the store by calling that URL so first you call base URL and then change store URL and then again call the base URL to get `0.99`cents price.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

dollars_pattern = '>([0-9][0-9]?)'
cents_pattern = '>([0-9][0-9])'


url = 'https://www.paknsaveonline.co.nz/CommonApi/Store/ChangeStore?storeId=65defcf2-bc15-490e-a84f-1f13b769cd22'
baseurl="https://www.paknsaveonline.co.nz/product/5039956_ea_000pns?name=broccoli"
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

with requests.session() as s:
  #I assume this url changes the store (200 response)
  s.get(baseurl)
  s.get(url)
  #use the same session to return broccoli price
  r = s.get(baseurl)
  soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
  cents =  str(soup.find_all('span', {'class': "fs-price-lockup__cents"}))
  dollars =  str(soup.find_all('span', {'class': "fs-price-lockup__dollars"}))
  centsprice =re.findall(cents_pattern, cents)
  dollarsprice = re.findall(dollars_pattern, dollars)
  print(dollarsprice, centsprice)
```

[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)